# Using the LinkedIn CM API, how do I get an organization by vanityName?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am building an app for posting to LinkedIn using the Community Management API. One of the feature is mentioning organization pages.

Before version 202308 everything was fine. I was using the organization lookup endpoint using the vanityName finder to access non admin fields. It used to work really well.

Now I just updated to version 202308 and keep getting 403 ACCESS_DENIED, with the message "Not enough permissions to access: organizations.FINDER-vanityName.20230801"

Nothing has been documented on the recent changes page : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/recent-changes?view=li-lms-2023-10&trk=eml-mktg-cust-202310-global-october-api-newsletter&mcid=7111165805462990848&src=e-eml

The finder method "vanityName" doesn't appear anymore on the developer solution portal when the version is set to 202308

Has it been removed ?

If so, how can we mention pages when there are no way of getting their IDs ?

For now I downgraded this endpoint to version 202307, but once this version gets deprecated I'm not sure how my app will work

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting the same error. It appears that this endpoint now requires the `r_compliance` scope, which I lack. According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/getting-access#compliance-closed, requesting access to this scope isn't possible. While downgrading to version `202307` allows the endpoint to function again, I'm also concerned about potential deprecation. If you discover any additional information or a workaround, please inform me (I will do the same).

Comment: FYI I opened a zendesk ticket a few days ago, still no answer.

Maybe you could do the same ? linkedin.zendesk.com

Comment: @tavoyne did you guys ever figure out a way to resolve this? We are running into the same issue.

Comment: Yes they replied to me a few days ago, its something on their end that will be release by december. We have to use the 202307 version in the mean time

Comment: I'm still having this issue, but it seems it work only on version 202306 and down and starts breaking on version 202307 and up. Weirdly, I'm seeing a 500 instead of a permission error... Filed a support request on Zendesk as well.

Comment: I am seeing the same thing now @Gregory did you get a response ?

Comment: Kindof @antoinechalifour.
They said they were working on it, but no mention of an ETA or anything concrete.
I suggest you create a ticket on Zendesk as well. The more of us do this, the more likely it is they will prioritize it I guess